# Are there any alternatives to Brightcove, now that support for Sitecore 7.2 is scheduled to end?

Tags: brightcove

A Brightcove module is available for Sitecore from the old SDN site, [Sitecore Media Framework Brightcove Edition](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20Media%20Framework/Brightcove.aspx), which integrates the Brightcove Video Cloud and the Sitecore Media Library

A number of [changes to the Brightcove Video Cloud Service](https://support.brightcove.com/node/16838) mean that this Brightcove module will stop working with Sitecore 7.2 from Dec 2017 onwards. We are on SC7.2 and planning an upgrade in Q2 2018.

Are there any alternatives available to continue using Brightcove with Sitecore after this date, or is it possible to perhaps purchase extended support for our Sitecore version until we have the upgrade in place?

[image]

Comment: Are they making breaking API changes which means it will stop working, or simply stopping support? Mainstream support for Sitecore 7.2 also ends in December 2017 as well btw: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/641167

Comment: Yes, based on our call with them the newer version is not backward compatible. Hence it will stop working.Which is a bit irking for us. Wondering how other folks across the globe are planning to handle this, if not upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have 2 options:

1. You could write your own connector for Brightcove. I know you are currently on 7.2 - but the 8.0+ Mediaframework Brightcove edition has been open sourced (*[Media-Framework-Brightcove-Edition](https://github.com/Sitecore/Media-Framework-Brightcove-Edition)*) so you could use that as a starting point to write a custom connector for 7.2
2. Move over to Ooyala - Ooyala is another video platform provider similar to Brightcove and there is a Mediaframework edition for Ooyala too. This would be a pretty big project tho depending on how many videos you have on your site.

There is a 3rd option too - move up the upgrade timescales, but that might not be feasible. I think the option with the least amount of risk would be to write a custom connector for the new Brightcove API.

Comment: Agree, discussed about the custom connector in one of the internal meetings today. Any more references you have which detailing out about the connector? Not sure what other folks are doing who are on 7.2 and using Brightcove.